# How can I set default parameter value for an action

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, default-value

How can I set default parameter value for an action when that parameter is dictionary type?

for example:

```
public void Test(Dictionary<int, bool> dic) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That method signature isn't valid. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

You can't give it a default value the way you want to because it has to be a compile time constant value, but you can do something like this:

```
private static bool Test(Dictionary<string, string> par = null)
    {
        if(par == null) par = GetMyDefaultValue();
        // Custom logic here
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `null` as special case, like in other answers, but if you still want to be able to call `Test(null)` and have different behaviour to calling `Test()`, then you must chain overload:

```
public void Test(Dictionary<int, bool> dic) {
  //optional, stops people calling Test(null) where you want them to call Test():
  if(dic == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("dic");
...
}

public void Test() {
   var defaultDic = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
   Test(defaultDic);
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution. Also, `Test()` should be `sealed`.

Comment: Furthermore, if you use null you don't know whether the caller used null as well, and you might instead want to catch that case and throw an exception, to make the API more clean.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth It is a must if you want to call `Test(null)` and have different result to calling `Test()`

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Have made it explicit. Cheers :)

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM Why `sealed`?

Comment: @weston It doesn't make sense to override `Test()` because it just provides a default behavior for `Test(Dictionary<..> ..)`. Suppose that in a subclass you override both `Test()` and `Test(...)` and implement different behaviors; that wouldn't be equivalent to the use of default parameters.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM Ah OK, it's not in the answer, but in my mind I sealed the `class` :D

Comment: @Ahmed You cannot apply the `sealed` keyword to a regular method, you can only apply it to an overridden method to prevent further derived classes from changing the implementation. Currently derived classes cannot override `Test` because it is not `virtual`, unless you mean making the class definition `sealed`...

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Good point, I fell for that because I've been doing a lot of java recently (where `virtual` is implied).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth @ weston Sorry guys. I too have been doing a lot of java recently.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `null` as a default parameter value for **reference types**.

> A default value must be one of the following types of expressions:
>
> - a constant expression;
> - an expression of the form `new ValType()`, where `ValType` is a value type, such as an `enum` or a `struct`;
> - an expression of the form `default(ValType)`, where `ValType` is a value type.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Comment: Well he can, a default of `null` can be provided and a little logic to default to something sensible if the item is `null`.

Comment: Yes, unless `null` is a valid parameter value.

Comment: I see where you are coming from, basically he cannot provide the exact default he wants in the method signature. Unfortunately, your answer is quite explicit and doesn't state that `null` is actually valid for a reference parameter.

Comment: `a constant expression;` and `null` is a constant expression; so I _explicitly_ said so.

Comment: Yes if someone new to the language knew that `null` was a constant expression and also one valid for `Dictionary<int, bool>`, this is all immediately preceded by "you can't" so I still feel it's unclear.

Comment: @weston It isn't 100% accurate. The OP asks if the dictionary can be defaulted, it *can*, to `null`. The very first words "you can't" are only correct if you make the assumption that the OP wants it defaulted to something other than null. Considering the OP hasn't actually stated it, my only gripe is that the answer doesn't go into explaining the available options.

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption that you want to provide a non-`null` default in the method signature, you cannot do that with this type. However, you have two alternative solutions 
that immediately spring to mind.

1, use optional parameters with a default, this will have to be `null` for a `Dictionary` (and all other reference types except `string` I believe) and you will need logic inside the method to handle it:

```
public void Test(Dictionary<int, bool> dictionary = null)
{
    // Provide a default if null.
    if (dictionary == null)
        dictionary = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
}
```

Or, and the way I'd do it, just use the "old fashioned" method overloading. This allows you to differentiate between people not providing the argument and people providing a `null` argument:

```
public void Test()
{ 
    // Provide your default value here.
    Test(new Dictionary<int, bool>();
}

public void Test(Dictionary<int, bool> dictionary)
{

}
```

Optional parameters compile into overloaded methods at any rate, so they are almost 
semantically the same, it's just a preference as to where you wish to express your default value.

Comment: see  this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/optional-parameters-and-named-arguments-in-c-4-and-a-cool-scenario-w-asp-net-mvc-2)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the dictionary to anything other then NULL. If you do try, for example:

`public void Test(Dictionary<int, bool> dic = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "1", "true" }})` or whatever, then you will see this error:

> Default parameter value for 'dic' must be a compile-time constant.

So in that case, `NULL` is your only choice. However, doing this is pointless

`public void Test(Dictionary<int, bool> dic = null)`

At worst the incoming `dic` will be `NULL` anyway, if the caller hasn't instantiated a new instance, so there is no advantage to adding the `NULL` default anyway.